# Quaternion.Lerp clock rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate the hand of the clock on click, but nothing is actually happening, none of the arrows is actually moving so I probably did something wrong... any help would be much appreciated, thank you

script below

```
public class Clock : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject minuteHand;
public GameObject hourHand;
private Quaternion targetRotation;
float speed = 0.1f;

void Start()
{
    targetRotation = transform.rotation;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        minuteHand.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(minuteHand.transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
} }
```

Comment: I dont understand the opinion of the minuteHand and hourHand cause you are not using hourhand ? you trying to rotate the gameobject with lerp am I right ? But you are setting targetRotation to current rotation and you are expecting to the rotate the object ? you should set different targetRotation

Comment: Why are you using Quaternion.Lerp()? Avoid using Quaternion methods if you can just use transform.Rotate() instead. With Rotate() you can just give the angle (and axis) you want to rotate each frame, and it will do the work.

Comment: @BobTheMinion did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is only executed exactly in one single frame when the mouse button goes down.

Also that is not how Lerp works. Lerp expects a factor between 0 and 1 and interpolates both values. If you multiply your speed (`0.1`) and the `Time.deltaTime` which for 60FPS has a value of about `1/60f = 0.017f` you get a resulting factor of about `0.0017f` => You will always stay pretty close to the first value

especially since additionally your `targetRotation` always equals the current `transform.rotation`!

---

I assume what you wanted is: Every click move the minute 6° ahead (360°/60 minutes = 6°/minute).

Once a full circle is done move the hour 30° ahead (360°/12 hours = 30°/hour)

```
public class Clock : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject minuteHand;
    public GameObject hourHand;

    Quaternion originalRotationMinute;
    Quaternion originalRotationHour;

    int minutes;
    int hours;

    // Store original orientations
    void Start()
    {
        originalRotationMinute = minuteHand.transform.rotation;
        originalRotationHour = hourHand.transform.rotation;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // First calculate the new time
            minutes++;
            if(minutes == 60)
            {
                minutes = 0;
                hours++;
                if(hours = 12)
                {
                    hours = 0;
                }
            }

            // Now update the rotations with the new time
            // I'm assuming here you want to rotate around the Z axis
            // if this is not the case change this according to your needs
            var targetMinuteRotation = originalRotationMinute * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 6.0f * minutes);
            var targetHourRotation = originalRotationHour * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 30.0f * hours);

            minuteHand.transform.rotation = targetMinuteRotation;
            hourHand.transform.rotation = targetHourRotation;
        }
    }
}
```

This would make the clock "jump" to the target rotations. If what you rather wanted is a smooth rotation (what I assume from the usage of Lerp) I would probably use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for that:

```
public class Clock : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject minuteHand;
    public GameObject hourHand;
    float speed = 0.1f;

    Quaternion originalRotationMinute;
    Quaternion originalRotationHour;

    int minutes;
    int hours;

    void Start()
    {
        originalRotationMinute = minuteHand.transform.rotation;
        originalRotationHour = hourHand.transform.rotation;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // cancel the current routines 
            StopAllCoroutines();

            // calculate the new time
            minutes++;
            if(minutes == 60)
            {
                minutes = 0;
                hours++;
                if(hours = 12) hours = 0;
            }

            // I'm assuming here you want to rotate around the Z axis
            // if this is not the case change this according to your needs
            var targetMinuteRotation = originalRotationMinute * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 6.0f * minutes);
            var targetHourRotation = originalRotationHour * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 30.0f * hours);

            // This time instead of directly setting the values start coroutines
            // to rotate the hands smoothly according to the given speed
            StartCoroutine (RotateTo(minuteHand, targetMinuteRotation));
            StartCoroutine (RotateTo(hourHand, targetHourRotation));
        }
    }

    // rotate the given object to the given target rotation
    // according to the given speed
    private IEnumerator RotateTo(GameObject obj, Quaternion targetRotation)
    {
        var targetTransform = obj.transform;
        var current = targetTransform.rotation;
        // I your are not rotating on the Z axis change this accordingly to your needs
        var difference = targetRotation.eulerAngels.z - current.eulerAngles.z;

        if(Mathf.Approximately(0, difference)) yield break;

       var duration = difference / speed;

       var timePassed = 0f;
       while(timePassed <= duration)
       {
           var factor = timePassed / duration;

           targetTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(current, targetRotation, factor);

           timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
           yield return null;
       }

       // t be sure set the final rotation once in the end
       targetTransform.rotation = targetRotation;
    }
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: please leave some questions for the rest of us to answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For me only this works. You can't modify speed to make it even slower, but it looks fine (may be it will be helpful to someone)

```
float speed = 0.1f //how fast rotate
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        nextRot = hour * -30;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, nextRot), speed);
     
    }
```